# Uget maximum active downloads

Tags: uget

How can I set the maximum number of active downloads in Uget. As default it's 3 downloads.
I searched but the only related thing I found was this:
`Active Downloads Limit Control: specify how many downloads each category is allowed to run simultaneously.`
[Source](http://ugetdm.com/features) -> Category Features

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Go to **Category > Properties** where you'll find the suitable setting for active downloads:

[image]

But note that maximum allowed limit is 20.

Comment: confirmed: from official project member

Comment: in my case, i have to left click on "All Category" =>"Property" to show this dialog
, Ubuntu uGet v2.2.2